# How to use spaces as delimiters to get a substring within a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a list of street addresses, some of which have po boxes. What I want to do is remove anything that isn't a po box from the line if it does contain a po box. For example, if there is a list of ['123 whatever drive', '234 anywhere lane po box 3213', 'po box 190 441 bettername street'] this should return ['123 whatever drive', 'po box 3213', 'po box 190'].
All I have thus far is

```
def listofaddr(lst)):
    boxes = ('po box ', 'p o box ')
    finstring = []
    for i in lst:
        if boxes in i:
            i = 'po box ' + 
        finstring.append(i)
```

What I think I can do is use the space after 'box' as a delimiter, grab the next substring of numbers after the space, and use the next space as a delimiter to end the string but I can't think of how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
a=['123 whatever drive', '234 anywhere lane po box 3213', 'po box 190 441 bettername street']
["po box "+e.split("po box ")[1].split(" ")[0] if "po box" in e else e for e in a]
```

Output:

```
['123 whatever drive', 'po box 3213', 'po box 190']
```

Comment: What in the world do `e` and `a` correspond to?

Comment: `a` is the input list. `e` is the loop variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, which is easy to test here: https://pythex.org/

```
import re
firstList = ['123 whatever drive', '234 anywhere lane po box 3213', 'po box 190 441 bettername street']
outputList = [re.search('[0-9]+', x)[0] if 'po box' in x else x for x in firstList]
```

Will output:

```
['123 whatever drive', 'po box 3213', 'po box 190']
```

Comment: `['123 whatever drive', 'po box 3213', 'po box 190']` is not the same as `['123 whatever drive', 'po box 3213', 'po box 190 441']`

Comment: This is not the intended result as per the OP's question.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa read the OP's question one more time. They don't want the 411. They just want the first set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
addrs = ['123 whatever drive', '234 anywhere lane po box 3213', 'po box 190 441 bettername street']
boxes = [(a[a.index('po box'):] if ('po box' in a) else a) for a in addrs]
```

I'm using simple string slicing here: if the string `'po box'` exists in any address `a`, cut off the part of the string before that point. Otherwise, just return the address `a`, and do this for all addresses `a` in `addrs`.

If you want to get more specific, you could look into using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) instead of string slicing.

Comment: I think they want the specific number after po box, not everything after po box

Comment: `['123 whatever drive', 'po box 3213', 'po box 190 441 bettername street']` is not `['123 whatever drive', 'po box 3213', 'po box 190']`